# Where to look for seforim funding?

Tags: jewish-books, money

I'm working on a book to bring iyun torah to everyone through a clear, English, user-friendly book of 11 essays of chiddushim in various talmudic topics. The idea is that learning in depth is unfortunately not so common for many people for a whole range of reasons, and so this project is aiming to help give iyun back to the entire frum community (and the not frum community too). I'm doing self-publishing as its the cheapest model. Now I've started fundraising and, besides, obviously, asking people in my city who I know, I wanted to know if there are any foundations  that look to support publication of sefarim and chiddushei Torah (as well as gevirim who are known to be into supporting sifrei Torah). Are there any such things? Which ones are they? how can I find them? Thanks very, very much!

Comment: Do you have any association with a Yeshiva or Kollel? Maybe you can go through them which might allow for more easily placed sponsors?

Comment: https://www.gofundme.com/